# Erro Gradle ao iniciar projeto React Native

Tags: linux, react-native, gradle

Gente, estou com problema ao iniciar um projeto React Native ao executar o comando `npx react-native run-android`. O erro é:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/home/temp/react_native_project/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /home/temp/react_native_project/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/home/temp/react_native_project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/temp/react_native_project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

Tem alguma coisa com versão do Gradle 7.0 mas não sei resolver.
Meu ambiente é:

- Linux 5.6.11-zen1-1-zen
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.62.2

Editado: dicionando package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react_native_project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Informação do comando: `android/gradlew --version`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-18 20:25:01 UTC
Revision:     fad121066a68c4701acd362daf4287a7c309a0f5

Kotlin:       1.3.50
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_242 (Oracle Corporation 25.242-b08)
OS:           Linux 5.6.11-zen1-1-zen amd64
```

Resolvido:

Eu tive que criar o projeto com o `npx`e criar arquivo **local.properties** na pasta android com conteudo `sdk.dir=/home/gui/Android/Sdk`. Feito isso, tudo funcionou.

Comment: Se você executar `./gradlew tasks` antes de `react-native run-android` funciona? [Aqui](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25992) tem outras sugestões.

Comment: Não, não funcionou. Executei um `./gradle clean`, removi a pasta **~/.gradle** e depois a **node_modules** do meu projeto. Executei o `npm install` e `./gradle tasks` no projeto, e quando executo `npx react-native run-android`me deparo com mesmo erro.

Comment: ...e estou usando dispositivo físico, já reconhecido com o comando `adb devices`

Comment: Consegui...eu tinha que criar o projeto com npx e criar arquivo local.properties na pasta android, e não tinha criado. Ao fazer isso, deu certo.

Comment: Faça uma resposta no campo aqui embaixo (fim da página). Não tem problema responder a sua própria pergunta e aceitar sua resposta como solução, não precisa colocar `[Resolvido]` no título da pergunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui...eu tinha que criar o projeto com npx e criar arquivo local.properties na pasta android, e não tinha criado. Ao fazer isso, deu certo.